# 1999 Toyota Camry Transmission issue

Tags: toyota, transmission, automatic-transmission, camry

I have a 1999 Toyota Camry. Bought it from dealership a year and 3 months ago. I went from 150,000 to 170,000 miles on the Odometer. Overtime the car started to shift rough (automatic vehicle). I changed the transmission fluid and even added the Lucas transmission repair. It still shifts rough. Car runs well, but it just jerks hard whenever it shifts gears. What could the issue be?

And on a side note, some people said it maybe a computer part need replacing but the Check engine light isn't on and no codes show up.

Comment: Not enough info here to give a full answer.  These transmissions are robust but can fail. If the fluid is clean and full and there no codes are present in the computer then it is most likely a mechanical type failure inside the transmission itself. The computers rarely fail and almost always set codes when the do. I know of no way to confirm what the failure is without having an automotive diagnostician inspect and drive the car.  Welcome to the sight.

Comment: Since you changed the fluid, has it retained it's nice bright red color? Or has it begun to darken into a cherry red, almost brown. If it's still that nice bright red, you're not generating excess heat in the transmission and it may be something outside the transmission itself. Does the tranny shift at the right points? Or is it delaying the shift to an abnormally high RPM?

Comment: BTW, is this the V6, or the 4 cylinder engine? The 4 cylinder should be the 5S-FE engine. I have a 2000 Camry LE with the 4 cylinder in it. Mine has 146,000 miles. And I have begun to notice it delays in shifting some. But the fluid looks really clean. We may both have issues with the vacuum lines that help tell the transmission when to shift. Please help use to help you. Which engine is it, and what is the color of the fluid. Pictures of the dip stick would be fantastic.